# Flutter driver with custom OTP verification and native functions (Toast)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, toast, flutterdriver

I'm using flutter to develop apps. Now stuck on the test cases,

I referred [flutter driver](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) for testing and it is working fine for simple UIs and flows.

I want to go through the login part, and **I have an OTP verification section** there, how do I pass this screen because I have to enter the pin that will receive at the verification time.

When I tried to check the native functions like toast (I'm using one library: [FlutterToast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast)) it is not catching the UI change. I tried with text catch

```
await driver.waitFor(find.text('Invalid credentials.'));
```

referred links:

1. https://blog.codemagic.io/integration-tests-codemagic/
2. https://medium.com/ionicfirebaseapp/an-introduction-to-integration-testing-for-flutter-app-b7d2b2af1739

Answer (score 0):

Do you solved this? Maybe try use another like toast widget if that widget can receive key.

Comment: yeah, changing the toast is a good thought. but I need the OTP entering.

Answer (score 0):

```
await driver.requestData('Invalid credentials.');
```

Use this for detecting toast. This worked for me.